# Edição em massa em curto espaço de tempo

Tags: debate

Hoje eu entrar na homepage, havia cerca de **25 perguntas editadas** por um mesmo usuário no período de uma hora. Aparentemente era adição de tags.

Não estou questionando o conteúdo da edição, mas sim o monopólio da homepage nesse horário.

O sistema não tem, ou deveria ter, um limite de edições em um curto espaço de tempo, dando uma mensagem do tipo "Vá com calma! Você já editou muitas perguntas!", e bloquear a edição por alguns minutos, ou talvez horas.

Acredito que isso seja raro de acontecer, e talvez não haja muito o que fazer. Mas de qualquer forma me incomodou um pouco, então lanço a questão pra discussão.

Comment: Não tem limite, mas é recomendado que se faça este tipo de edições em massa em horários de pouco movimento.

Comment: O usuário em questão é um moderador? Se sim, vamos supor que ele saiba o que está fazendo. Se não, é bom alertá-lo e talvez esse aviso até faria sentido.

Comment: Essa aqui também é um bom complemento: [Como fazer edições massivas de tags?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1768)

Comment: Foi o @Sorack, acredito que as mudanças que ele realizou são pertinentes, só fiquei de avisá-lo quanto aos melhores horários para isso, mas acabei chamando ele no chat e esqueci de passar o recado.

Comment: Acho que é moderador não. A pergunta sinalizada como duplicada tem haver sim com esse, mas ela foi lançada na época do beta parece, o contexto pode ter mudado, mas vou ler com atenção e  talvez aceitar a resposta dela.